# I Need Help, Problems with Foreach and JSON

Tags: php, json, foreach

I'm doing a foreach through PHP, in a JSON as follows example below:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "NAME": "Enterprise 1",
        "DOC": "0000000000001",
        "EST": "1"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "NAME": "Enterprise 2",
        "DOC": "0000000000003",
        "EST": "3"
    }
]
```

But, when using foreach with PHP, it only returns me the last JSON record, what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
  $Enterprise = JSON_Decode($JSON, true);

  foreach($Enterprise as $Key => $Ent);
  {echo $Ent['NAME'].'</br>';}
?>
```

Instead of returning Enterprise to me on each line, it just returns me Enterprise 2. Any suggestions?

Comment: Because the `;` terminates the `foreach` and the one `echo` is executed after. Remove the `;`

Comment: And you'll always get back the last element as you've traversed the Array and $Ent is still in-scope.

Comment: Thanks my friend, It was really the `;`, I had not even noticed it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems you have a stray semicolon right after your `foreach` which results in an empty loop body.

`foreach($Enterprise as $Key => $Ent);`

Remove the semicolon, and your `foreach` body will execute as expected.

Comment: What a `;` does not cause haha, I'm sorry for the inconvenience, I did not really see.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can slightly modify your original code. The problem is just about a common `;` issue:

```
$Enterprise = '[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "NAME": "Enterprise 1",
        "DOC": "0000000000001",
        "EST": "1"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "NAME": "Enterprise 2",
        "DOC": "0000000000003",
        "EST": "3"
    }
]';

$Enterprise = json_decode($Enterprise, true);

foreach ($Enterprise as $Key => $Ent) {

    echo $Ent['NAME'] . "\n";

}
```

#### Output

```
Enterprise 1
Enterprise 2
```

Comment: Yes, this `;` at the end of the foreach line was the problem ... had not seen .

Comment: You didn't actually mention _what_ you changed, it may not be incredibly obvious to every reader. Your answer is basically "To fix your issue, we just have to modify your code {code dump}"